# How To Integrate HTMLHint into Codemirror 6

Tags: html, codemirror, codemirror-6, htmlhint

I'm trying to add HTMLHint into Codemirror 6 by following the [lint documentation](https://codemirror.net/examples/lint/) and the [eslint-linter-browserify](https://github.com/UziTech/eslint-linter-browserify/blob/HEAD/example) demo for Codemirror 6. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but the lints are not showing.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how can I add HTMLHint into Codemirror 6?

**lang-html:**

```
function HTMLHint(htmlhint, config) {
    config = {
        rules: {
            "tagname-lowercase": true,
            "attr-lowercase": true,
            "attr-value-double-quotes": true,
            "doctype-first": true,
            "tag-pair": true,
            "spec-char-escape": true,
            "id-unique": true,
            "src-not-empty": true,
            "attr-no-duplication": true
        }
    }
    return (view) => {
        let { state } = view, found = [];
        for (let { from, to } of htmlLanguage.findRegions(state)) {
            let fromLine = state.doc.lineAt(from), offset = { line: fromLine.number - 1, col: from - fromLine.from, pos: from };
            for (let d of htmlhint.verify(state.sliceDoc(from, to)))
                found.push(translateDiagnostic(d, state.doc, offset));
        }
        return found;
    };
}
function mapPos(line, col, doc, offset) {
    return doc.line(line + offset.line).from + col + (line == 1 ? offset.col - 1 : -1);
}
function translateDiagnostic(input, doc, offset) {
    let start = mapPos(input.line, input.column, doc, offset);
    let result = {
        from: start,
        to: input.endLine != null && input.endColumn != 1 ? mapPos(input.endLine, input.endColumn, doc, offset) : start,
        message: input.message,
        source: input.ruleId ? "htmlhint:" + input.ruleId : "htmlhint",
        severity: input.severity == 1 ? "warning" : "error",
    };
    if (input.fix) {
        let { range, text } = input.fix, from = range[0] + offset.pos - start, to = range[1] + offset.pos - start;
        result.actions = [{
                name: "fix",
                apply(view, start) {
                    view.dispatch({ changes: { from: start + from, to: start + to, insert: text }, scrollIntoView: true });
                }
            }];
    }
    return result;
}

export { autoCloseTags, HTMLHint, html, htmlCompletionSource, htmlCompletionSourceWith, htmlLanguage };
```

**editor.js:**

```
import { EditorView } from '@codemirror/view';
import { lineNumbers, highlightActiveLineGutter, highlightSpecialChars, drawSelection, dropCursor, rectangularSelection, crosshairCursor, highlightActiveLine, keymap } from '@codemirror/view';
import { EditorState } from '@codemirror/state';
import { foldGutter, indentOnInput, syntaxHighlighting, defaultHighlightStyle, bracketMatching, foldKeymap } from '@codemirror/language';
import { history, defaultKeymap, historyKeymap } from '@codemirror/commands';
import { highlightSelectionMatches, searchKeymap } from '@codemirror/search';
import { closeBrackets, autocompletion, closeBracketsKeymap, completionKeymap } from '@codemirror/autocomplete';
import { linter, lintKeymap, lintGutter } from '@codemirror/lint';
import { javascript } from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";
import { html, HTMLHint } from "@codemirror/lang-html";
import { htmlhint } from 'htmlhint';

// ruleSets for HTMLLint
let ruleSets = {
  "tagname-lowercase": true,
  "attr-lowercase": true,
  "attr-value-double-quotes": true,
  "doctype-first": false,
  "tag-pair": true,
  "spec-char-escape": true,
  "id-unique": true,
  "src-not-empty": true,
  "attr-no-duplication": true
};

const basicSetup = [
    lineNumbers(),
    highlightActiveLineGutter(),
    highlightSpecialChars(),
    history(),
    foldGutter(),
    drawSelection(),
    dropCursor(),
    EditorState.allowMultipleSelections.of(true),
    indentOnInput(),
    syntaxHighlighting(defaultHighlightStyle),
    bracketMatching(),
    closeBrackets(),
    autocompletion(),
    rectangularSelection(),
    crosshairCursor(),
    highlightActiveLine(),
    highlightSelectionMatches(),
    lintGutter(),
    linter(HTMLHint(ruleSets)),
    keymap.of([
        ...closeBracketsKeymap,
        ...defaultKeymap,
        ...searchKeymap,
        ...historyKeymap,
        ...foldKeymap,
        ...completionKeymap,
        ...lintKeymap,
    ]),
    html(),
];

const editor = new EditorView({
  state: EditorState.create({
    doc: `<span id="hi">hello world</span>
<span id="hi">hello world</span>`,
    extensions: [basicSetup],
  }),
  parent: document.getElementById('editor'),
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>CodeMirror 6 Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="editor"></div>
    </main>
    
    <script src="editor.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was able to accomplish this with Codemirror v5- with....

```
// CodeMirror, copyright (c) by Marijn Haverbeke and others
// Distributed under an MIT license: https://codemirror.net/5/LICENSE

// Depends on htmlhint.js from http://htmlhint.com/js/htmlhint.js

// declare global: HTMLHint

(function(mod) {
  if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
    mod(require("../../lib/codemirror"), require("htmlhint"));
  else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
    define(["../../lib/codemirror", "htmlhint"], mod);
  else // Plain browser env
    mod(CodeMirror, window.HTMLHint);
})(function(CodeMirror, HTMLHint) {
  "use strict";

  var defaultRules = {
    "tagname-lowercase": true,
    "attr-lowercase": true,
    "attr-value-double-quotes": true,
    "doctype-first": false,
    "tag-pair": true,
    "spec-char-escape": true,
    "id-unique": true,
    "src-not-empty": true,
    "attr-no-duplication": true
  };

  CodeMirror.registerHelper("lint", "html", function(text, options) {
    var found = [];
    if (HTMLHint && !HTMLHint.verify) {
      if(typeof HTMLHint.default !== 'undefined') {
        HTMLHint = HTMLHint.default;
      } else {
        HTMLHint = HTMLHint.HTMLHint;
      }
    }
    if (!HTMLHint) HTMLHint = window.HTMLHint;
    if (!HTMLHint) {
      if (window.console) {
          window.console.error("Error: HTMLHint not found, not defined on window, or not available through define/require, CodeMirror HTML linting cannot run.");
      }
      return found;
    }
    var messages = HTMLHint.verify(text, options && options.rules || defaultRules);
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      var message = messages[i];
      var startLine = message.line - 1, endLine = message.line - 1, startCol = message.col - 1, endCol = message.col;
      found.push({
        from: CodeMirror.Pos(startLine, startCol),
        to: CodeMirror.Pos(endLine, endCol),
        message: message.message,
        severity : message.type
      });
    }
    return found;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `javascriptLanguage.findRegions` method in your HTMLHint function to find the parts of the page to lint, however this is wrong.
Because you're working with HTML rather than JavaScript, you should use the `htmlLanguage.findRegions` function instead.
Additionally, before you can utilise the `htmlhint` module in the `linter` extension, you must import it in your `editor.js` file.

Comment: Noticed that fixed but problem persists